# Waiting for task to be finished

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services, task

I am pasting a snippet of windows service I have written.
For the task to be finished I changed the default service kill time to 30 minutes.

```
       private static void TaskMethod1()
       {
          //I am doing a bunch of operations here, all of them can be replaced with a sleep for 25 minutes
       }

       private static async Task TaskMethod()
       {
           while(runningService)
           {
              // Thi will create more than one task in parallel to run and each task can take upto 30 minutes to finish
              Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1);
           }
       }
       internal static void Start()
        {
            runningService = true;
            Task1 = Task.Run(() => TaskMethod());
        }

        internal static void Stop()
        {
            runningService = false;
            Task1.Wait();
        }
```

In the above code, I have written `Task1.wait()` which waits for task1 to be finished but not for all the tasks created in `TaskMethod` i.e. tasks executing `TaskMethod1`.
I have the following questions:

1. How can I make the service to wait for tasks created using `Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1);`.(Note that there might be more than one tasks created for `Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1);` but `Task1 = Task.Run(() => TaskMethod());` is run only once.)
2. when I run `Task1.wait()` why doesn't it wait for all the tasks created as a part of that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You would have to keep track of the tasks you create to be able to refer to them later. For example:

```
private static List<Task> _taskList = new List<Task>();

private static void TaskMethod()
{
   while(runningService)
   {
      // This will create more than one task in parallel to run and each task can take upto 30 minutes to finish
      _taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1)));
   }
}

internal static void Stop()
{
    runningService = false;
    Task.WaitAll(_taskList.ToArray());
    Task1.Wait();
}
```

2. Because `Task1` isn't dependent on the completion of the other tasks. In `TaskMethod()`, you're just creating the `Task` and moving on. There is nothing in there that tells it to wait for anything. Unless you `await` or `.Wait()` on the `Task` returned from `Task.Run`, your code just continues to run with no dependency on the `Task` you just created.

That's a problem I see in your code as you have it. Your `while(runningService)` loop will loop as fast as your CPU will allow, creating thousands of new tasks in seconds. Are you sure that's what you want?

Maybe you want it to wait inside the loop for it to complete, before looping and starting a new one? If I'm correct, then your loop should look like this:

```
private static async Task TaskMethod()
{
   while(runningService)
   {
      // This will create more than one task in parallel to run and each task can take upto 30 minutes to finish
      await Task.Run(() => TaskMethod1(arg1));
   }
}
```

But that would only create one `Task` at a time.

Comment: `_taskList.WaitAll(_taskList.ToArray());` should be `Task.WaitAll(_taskList.ToArray());` right?

Comment: @sporty_1993 Yes, sorry.